# Conditional information of two Bernoulli random variables given their sum

Tags: information-theory

Let random variables X,Y independent Bernoulli random variables,   $Z=X+Y$

I need to calculate the I (X:Y|X+Y)

So obviously,  I get :

\begin{eqnarray*}
I(X;Y|Z)&=&H(X|Z)-H(X|Y,Z)
\end{eqnarray*}

also we know that $H(X|Y) = H(X)$ because they are independent.
The thing is here i am stuck. can i get an explanation please? 
Thanks!

Comment: How are you defining $I$ and $H$?

Comment: @Math1000 these are standard notation for mutual information & Shannon entropy respectively, which given the information theory tag shouldn't need explicit definition.

Comment: @Xander is the plus in $Z = X+Y$ standard addition, or XOR? In either case, knowing both $Z$ and $Y$ determines $X$ perfectly, so $H(X|Y,Z) = 0.$ In the case of standard addition, when $Z = 2$ or $0$, knowing $Z$ fixes $X$ - I.e. $H(X| Z = 0) = H(X|Z = 2) = 0.$ Find $P(X = 1|Z=1)$ to figure out the entropy $H(X|Z = 1)$, and then use the definition of conditional entropy to conclude. If XOR, then it is easy to show that $Z$ and $X$ are also (marginally) independent.

Comment: @stochasticboy321 thank you very much!

I think i get it. Many thanks!